# Dynamically build a condition on a DataTable using a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable

Currently I can query my `DataTable` (*dtContacts*) like this:
If I am looking for a person whose `FirstName` is "John" and `LastName` is "Smith". My result will be

```
DataTable dt = dtContacts.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<string>("FirstName") == "John" && c.Field<string>("LastName") == "Smith").CopyToDataTable();
```

But such static querying does not help me because my conditions may be slightly more complicated than this. So I would like my LINQ to be a bit more dynamic so it can accommodate the following scenario.

I am going to save my condition in a `Dictionary<string,string>` like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicConditions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dicConditions.Add("FirstName", "John");
dicConditions.Add("LastName", "Smith");
dicConditions.Add("IsCustomer", "Yes");
```

Note that we can add as many conditions as we want to this dictionary.
And let's assume that the main `DataTable` *dtContacts* always contains the column names that are mentioned in the dictionary keys so we do not need to check for that every time.

In the new version we would like our LINQ to act according to `dicConditions` and return all the values whose `FirstName` is "John", `LastName` is "Smith" and `IsCustomer` is "Yes".

How should this new dynamic LINQ query look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
DataTable dt = dtContacts
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(c => 
        dicConditions.All(kv => c.Field<string>(kv.Key) == kv.Value)
    ).CopyToDataTable();
```

The idea is to apply LINQ twice - once to the `dtContacts`, and once to `dicConditions` inside the `Where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the predicate you showed above from a dictionary using an approach like this:

```
using StringKvp = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>;
using DataRowPredicate = System.Func<System.Data.DataRow, bool>;
...

var pred = dicConditions.Aggregate<StringKvp, DataRowPredicate>(r => true,
    (net, curr) => r => net(r) && r.Field<string>(curr.Key) == curr.Value);
```

Then it is just a matter of filtering your collection with this predicate:

```
var dt = dtContacts.AsEnumerable().Where(pred).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
var result= dtContacts.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(r=>dicConditions.All(d=>r[d.key]==d.Value));
```

You may need to properly convert the values of the dictionary to be compatible with the datatable...
Use Regex to support wildcards...etc...